# Adding Digits in a Number (Need Code Explanation)

Tags: python, algorithm, sum-of-digits

I came across this code segment elsewhere. It simply adds all the digits in a given number:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    sum = 0
    while n > 0:
        sum += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return sum
```

Problem is, I don't get the logic behind it at all. In particular, I don't get exactly what the loop does:

```
   while n > 0:
        sum += n % 10  # Why n % 10?
        n //= 10       # Again, not sure why we divide the number by 10
```

Could someone provide me with an example of how the algorithm works?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the `%` operator does? Have you considered looking at what `n % 10` is and how `n` changes with each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the modulus operator. I was just unsure of its use in this situation. I've tried tracing it on paper but still couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: `print(n, sum)` in the loop ?

Comment: `sum([int(i) for i in str(n)])` . Instead of the algorithm. You can try this also. It's out of the conversation i know. I just mentioned an alternative option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should understand 2 things:

1. `n % 10` give you the rightmost digit of a number. For example: `123 % 10 = 3`
2. `n // 10` remove the rightmost digit of a number. For example: `123 // 10 = 12`

so if you repeat that process you get the desired result

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch! I certainly didn't know that.

Comment: It does so for numbers represented in the decimal system (base 10), so for any base b (integer > 1) and number n represented in the system with base b the operation n % b yields the rightmost digit and n //= b removes the rightmost digit through augmented integer division. In Python 2 codes sometimes also n /= b may be found.